# VBA - How do I reference the last row of data for Range?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

My Excel workbook has a summary Recap sheet that pulls data from the proceeding detail sheets (with new detail sheets being added frequently).

When a new detail sheet is added, I want my macro insert a new row at the end of the Recap sheet, format that row with the same formatting as the other rows in the Recap sheet (I grabbed row 37 for simplicity), and populate the cells in the new Recap row with the data from the newly added detail sheet.

I'm getting the error "Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed" when I try to have VBA select the last row to paste the formatting of row A37:X37.

Then I need to change "B38" to be B[row # of last row]. (I can't use a specific row # because many new rows will continue to be added.)

Please note I'm pretty new to VBA.

Here's what I have:

```
Function GetLastSheetName() As String
    Dim wbk As Excel.Workbook

    Set wbk = Excel.ActiveWorkbook
    GetLastSheetName = wbk.Worksheets(wbk.Worksheets.Count).Name
End Function
Sub AddToRecap()
'
' AddToRecap Macro
' Add show info to Recap sheet
'

'
Dim strLastSheetName As String

strLastSheetName = GetLastSheetName()

Dim Lastrow As Integer
Lastrow = Sheets("Recap").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

    Sheets("Recap").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Insert
    
    Range("A37:X37").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("Lastrow").EntireRow.Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("A37").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A37:A38"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("A37:A38").Select
    Range("B38").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='" & strLastSheetName & "'!R[-29]C"
    Range("B38").Select
End Sub
```

[image: Screenshot of code - error highlighted]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

Here it is, in case anyone is looking for something similar.

```
Function GetLastSheetName() As String
    Dim wbk As Excel.Workbook

    Set wbk = Excel.ActiveWorkbook
    GetLastSheetName = wbk.Worksheets(wbk.Worksheets.Count).Name
End Function
Sub AddToRecap()
'
' AddToRecap Macro
' Add show info to Recap sheet
'

'
Dim strLastSheetName As String

strLastSheetName = GetLastSheetName()

Dim Lastrow As Integer
Lastrow = Sheets("Recap").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

    Sheets("Recap").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Insert
    
    Range("A37:X37").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("A" & Lastrow).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("A37").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A37:A" & Lastrow), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("A37:A" & Lastrow).Select
    Range("B" & Lastrow).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='" & strLastSheetName & "'!R[-29]C"
    Range("B" & Lastrow).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).